# What is best way to compare dates in WHERE clause without functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, datetime

I'm looking over a script that I inherited and found this in the WHERE clause:

```
  WHERE
    CONVERT(DATE, changedon) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))
```

This is getting all records where changedon = the previous day's date.

I know you shouldn't use functions in the WHERE clause so I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite this.  The "changedon" field is a date/time so I'm confused as to how to do this without using CONVERT or CAST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, using functions is fine in this case.  The issue is whether or not SQL Server will use indexes, and it makes an exception for casting date/times to dates.  I think this is the only exception.

You can also rewrite this as:

```
WHERE changedon >= CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()))  AND
      changedon < CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Using functions on columns is normally the problem, as it makes it non-SARGable. Using them on functions, however, like `GETDATE` isn't an issue, as `GETDATE` doesn't have an index on it.

Comment: I understand it's okay to use functions with GetDate, since that's not a column.  But is it okay to use it with the ChangedOn field here, or is it better to rewrite it?

Comment: @jackstraw22 my comment explains that above.

Comment: @Lamu--my comment was actually referring to Gordon's answer where he wrote "it makes an exception for casting datetimes to dates."

Comment: It's RN, not M.

Comment: @larnu . . . I'm laughing.  It really does look like an "m" in the fonts that Stack Exchange uses.

Answer (score 0):

When you want filter a field in sql query, if you use a function on the field, the database has to process the all record and apply function to get result. This way costs a lot and very slow even indexed field. The best way to get best result is **use the function in filter value**
For example :

```
Select * from mytable t where t.field-1 = x
```

Database has to process all record in mytable.
Best query :

```
Select * from mytable t where t.field = x+1
```

I hop this is useful.